# Can I measure branch prediction failures on modern Intel Mac OS X?

Tags: xcode, macos, optimization, profiling, branch-prediction

I would like to measure branch prediction fails on Xcode for Intel processors on Mac OS X, with the obvious intent of speed optimization.

Is there a way to program XCode's Instruments in order to achieve this?

I have already checked, and this information is unfortunately not present in Xcode documentation. 
I suspect this could be achieved with some custom setting.

The purpose is identifying optimization problems such as this one:
[Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902)

I am aware that an [Intel commercial solution](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe) exists, for Intel Processors running on Linux and Windows. On OS X you can apparently only monitor a remote Intel processor running on a Linux or Windows system.

Rather than a commercial tool, I would prefer a way to set/program Xcode and Apple tools to gain at least a minimum of visibility on this issue.

Comment: I don't know about XCode, but Cachegrind can do it. http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html

Comment: I found out that an OS X compatible version of Cachegrind exists, looks promising. I will compile it and try it out. On another side, I noticed that the Counters instruments in Xcode profiling tools (which is deeply undocumented) seems to allow "counting" what looks to be exactly branch prediction failures.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else struggling with this, in Instruments 9.2:

- Select Counters
- Go to File>Recording Options
- Select "Sample by: Events"
- Choose an event name (see [docs](https://download.01.org/perfmon/index/skylake.html)), in this case "BR_MISP_RETIRED.CONDITIONAL":

[image: Screenshot of Recording Options in Instruments]

Answer (score 2):

There are hardware performance counters (PMC) in XCode's Instuments:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MeasuringCPUUse.html

There are hidden by default branch events in `Window > Manage PM Events`, according to
http://meandmark.com/blog/2011/10/event-profiler-and-counters-instruments/